# How should I bond two pieces of metal without a welder?

Tags: metal, support, joints, welding

I'm unable to access a welder at the moment as advised by my doctor but I'm needing to weld a couple of pieces of metal together for my grand daughter's birthday gift. It needs to be quite strong, able to support at least 150 kg (for multiple kids) so I'm feeling skeptical as to whether it's possible. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Drill holes and bolt through.

Comment: Or send it out to a local welding shop.

Comment: attach metal how?  two sheets on top of each other?  two edges at a 90 degree angle?  A diagram or description of how you want things joined would help figure out your options.